pycapnp: imported type is not visible
Imported type is not visible when using pycapnp.
I have 2 files, first is vec1.capnp
@0xf449cc59f43990cf;
struct Vec {
  x @0: Float64;
}

and the 2nd is vec2.capnp
@0xf449cc59f43990c0;
using Vec = import "vec1.capnp".Vec;
struct Vec2 {
  x @0: Float64;
  y @1: Vec;
}

When creating a new message with
import capnp
capnp.remove_import_hook()
schema = capnp.load('vec2.capnp')
instance = schema.Vec2.new_message()
print(instance)

the result is
(x = 0)

y is missing. Vec is also missing when listing all types of the schema.

The attribute y is there, in the instance, and you can find it in the instance class if calling dir(instance). Also it will appear in the print as soon as you'll call y at least once.  I guess capnp is doing lazy initialisation for custom types, thus you won't see attribute until you'll try to access it first.
import capnp

capnp.remove_import_hook()
schema = capnp.load('vec2.capnp')
instance = schema.Vec2.new_message()
instance.y
print(instance)
# Outputs: (x = 0, y = (x = 0))

or
instance = schema.Vec2.new_message(y = {})
print(instance)
# Outputs: (x = 0, y = (x = 0))


Thanks a lot, That helped. Well, at least a bit. Actually, I'm creating a script that builds C++ classes from schema files. It works for single files without the using statements, but it fails to resolve imported elements. I tried too loop over the fields of instances (like above) or to traverse the schema.node objects. But for imported elements I cannot resolve the node ids to get the details.

sry, not sure that I did understand everything from your comment. Could you please add an example of what you are doing in the question.

Sorry, I messed that up. I added my example as new answer.

See new question
